# How to show that solutions to differential equation are linearly dependent?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I do not know how to approach the following problem:

Suppose that $x_1(t), x_2(t), ..., x_n(t)$ are solution to the $n \times n$ homogeneous system $x' = Ax$. 
Suppose that the vectors $x_1(t_0), x_2(t_0), ..., x_n(t_0)$ are linearly dependent for a single value $t_0$. 
There are numbers $x_1(t), x_2(t), ..., x_n(t)$, not all zero, such that $c_1 x_1(t_0) + c_2 x_2(t_0) + c_n x_n(t_0) = 0$. 
Show that $x_1(t), x_2(t), ..., x_n(t)$ are linearly dependent for all values of t. (Hint: the uniqueness theorem says there is a unique solution x(t) satisfying $x(t_0) = 0$. What is it? Now consider $x(t) = c_1x_1(t) + ... + c_nx_n(t)$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There exists $c_1,\dots,c_n$ such that $c_1x_1(t_0)+\dots+c_nx_n(t_0)=0.$ Now, $$u_1(t)=c_1x_1(t)+\dots+c_nx_n(t)$$ is a solution that satisfies $u_1(t_0)=0.$ Of course $u_2(t)\equiv 0.$ Because of the uniticity of the solution we have that $$u_1(t)\equiv u_2(t)\equiv 0.$$ That is

$$c_1x_1(t)+\dots+c_nx_n(t)\equiv 0,$$ wich shows that $x_1(t),\dots, x_n(t)$ are lineraly dependent, $\forall t$.